# Can we simplify the sum $\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{((i-k)a)^i b^{k-i}}{i!}$?

Tags: factorial, summation

The problome is rewriten here:
     $\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{((i-k)a)^i b^{k-i}}{i!}$
where $0<a<1$, k is an integer larger than 1.

I came to this equation when i try to find some probability. I have tried some formulas on permutation and combination, fractional, but with little improvement.

I hope you can give me some sugestions! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question? How do you want to simplify this?

Comment: It is equivalent to $\sum_{i=0}^k\prod_{j=1}^i (1-\frac{k}{i})a$. Is this helpful?

Comment: I want to get an expression without factorials or \sum operations.

Comment: Does [] mean floor or brackets?

Comment: They are only brackets. I have replaced [] with ().

Comment: Since it is a finite sum, try writing the first few terms and the last few terms, perhaps there is some simplification.